# DRF: data is not passing to kwargs in patch method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a update comment view for my app. This is my code:

**serializer.py**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FitnessRecord
        fields = ('comment', 'id')
```

**views.py**

```
class AddCommentView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs) # this is printing {}
        instance = get_object_or_404(FitnessRecord, pk=kwargs.get('id')) # error line
        print(22222) # not printing
        serializer = CommentSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()

            return Response(CommentSerializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am using postman to send data. this is the error:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

This may be because kwargs is blank.

I am passing this data.

```
{
    "comment": "gotham#bw9",
    "id": 14
}
```

This is DRF setting if required.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ['%d-%m-%Y'],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

Comment: You are passing the data is the request body, it will be accessed in request.data and not in kwargs

Comment: Please attach your urls.py, maybe you didn't consider to pass `id`.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the kwarg `id` in the url. See example below

## URL:

```py
http://localhost:8000/comment/14/
```

## Request method: PATCH

## Data:

```py
{
    "comment": "gotham#bw9",
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. In adding url: path('add_comment/<id>/', views.AddCommentView.as_view()), and url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add_comment/14/ but this giving page not found error

Comment: I changed the url to this: path('add_comment/<id>/', views.AddCommentView.as_view(), name='add_comment'), and again "Not Found" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can get sent payload with `request.data`;

```py
def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.data) # this will print {"comment": "gotham#bw9", "id": 14}
    ...
```